# If else function....how to use return

Tags: process

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int GetPositiveInt();
int main (void)
{
    int min; /*variable to hold minutes*/
    printf ("How many minutes does it take you to use a shower?");
    scanf ("%d", &min);
    int numbtl = min * 12; /*computes number of bottles*/
    if (min > 0)
    {
        printf ("Taking a shower you use %d bottles of water", numbtl);
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("Please enter the positive number: \n");
        scanf ("%d", &min);}
        return min;
    }
}
```

I've written this program but I've got some bug in else place.
Here is the text which I get trying to execute this program.

```
~/workspace/pset1/ $ make water
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wshadow    water.c  -lcs50 -lm -o water
~/workspace/pset1/ $ ./water
How many minutes does it take you to use a shower?0
Please enter the positive number: 
10
~/workspace/pset1/ $
```

Let me explin what I mean by this code and its execution. This code is used to compute how many bottles of water you use while taking a shower. 1 minute of shower equals 12 bottles.

If you enter the positive integer (for example, 10) the result will be like this:Taking a shower you use 120 bottles of water. BUT if you enter 0 or negative integer the program will ask you to enter the positive integer. And here is when the problem occurs. After entering the positive integer I get the result of 0 bottles.

Comment: You have a typo: `esle`, I assume that is a copy paste error as the code would not compile this way.

Comment: Please read our FAQ. This is a Unix and Linux group.

Comment: @MichaelDaffin Thanks. I've changed it but I still have the same problem. After entering not a positive integer I am asked a question and then I am directed to workspace for some reason.

Comment: Your run session matches the code as written (apart from the typo of `esle`). I don't think there's a bug in the `else` section so much as a bug in the design. Follow it through on paper. What code gets run at the end of the `else` section? What code gets run after the `if ... then ... else` section? (Hint: what you think the `return` statement should do may well not match what the statement actually does.)

Comment: @roaima Yeah...I guess that the problem is with return section and I think I should change it for something else. The case is I am new to programming. This is my first program in C and I feel a bit uncomfortable. Maybe you could suggest me appropiate function. 
I would be very grateful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Lets break down your program and see what it is doing; first

```
int GetPositiveInt();
```

Is a [forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) for a function that is never used or defined, you can remove it entirely.

```
int main (void)
{
    int min; /*variable to hold minutes*/
    printf ("How many minutes does it take you to use a shower?");
    scanf ("%d", &min);
```

Here we define the main function (the entry point to a c program) and declare a variable of type `int` called `min`. Then print out a line asking for user input and read in their response storing it in the `min` variable.

```
    int numbtl = min * 12; /*computes number of bottles*/
```

Here you process `min` by multiplying it by 12 and storing the result in `numbtl`.

```
    if (min > 0)
    {
        printf ("Taking a shower you use %d bottles of water", numbtl);
    }
```

Here you check if `min` is valid, if it is you print the response. Here you can see the success path of your program is correct, the problem is what happens when `min` is not greater than 0. (Note there was a minor formatting error in this next bit that I corrected by what I assume you meant - note that this is why correct indenting and formatting is important).

```
    else
    {
        printf ("Please enter the positive number: \n");
        scanf ("%d", &min);
    }
```

If `min` is not valid (ie less than or equal to 0) then you ask for another input and store it in `min`.

```
    return min;
}
```

Lastly you return whatever is stored in min. Note you never actually do anything with this second value, except return it.

Side note: The return value on main is used as the exit status of your application. You can see the exit status of the last command in bash with `echo $?`.

```
$ ./water
How many minutes does it take you to use a shower?
2
Taking a shower you use 24 bottles of water
$ echo $?
2
```

This is probably not what you want. The exit status is normally 0 to indicate success and a positive number otherwise. This last return you will likely want `return 0` to indicate your program has run successfully.

Now for the logic of your program, what it looks like you are trying to do is obtain some input from the user; validate it (obtaining new input if its invalid); then process it. So the first thing to do is move your processing to the end of your program

```
int main (void)
{
    int min; /*variable to hold minutes*/
    ...
    int numbtl = min * 12; /*computes number of bottles*/
    printf ("Taking a shower you use %d bottles of water", numbtl);
    return 0;
}
```

Now we just need to acquire and validate the user input; a typical algorithm to do this is:

```
prompt for user input
while (input is not valid) {
    reprompt for user input
}
process user input
```

Converting this to c your applications ends up with;

```
int main (void)
{
    int min; /*variable to hold minutes*/
    printf ("How many minutes does it take you to use a shower? ");
    scanf ("%d", &min);
    while (min <= 0)
    {
        printf ("Please enter the positive number: ");
        scanf ("%d", &min);
    }
    int numbtl = min * 12; /*computes number of bottles*/
    printf ("Taking a shower you use %d bottles of water", numbtl);
    return 0;
}
```

This will continue to ask the user for a positive number until they either enter one or hit <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to kill the command. Once a valid number has been obtained it will processes it and print out the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    long min;
    char msg[255];

    strcpy(msg,"How many minutes does it take you to use a shower?\n");

    do {
            printf ("%s", msg);
            scanf ("%lu", &min);
            strcpy(msg , "Please enter the positive number: \n");

    }while( min <= 0 );



    long numbtl = min * 12; /*computes number of bottles*/

    printf ("Taking a shower you use %lu bottles of water", numbtl);


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a goto label. Here I used a goto label named start. If a number less than zero is entered then the program goes to beginning of the program. Hope, It helps.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int min; /*variable to hold minutes*/
    start :
    printf ("How many minutes does it take you to use a shower?\nEnter here : ");
    scanf ("%d", &min);
    if (min <= 0)
    {
       printf("Enter a number grater than zero\n\n");
       goto start;
    }
    int numbtl = min * 12; /*computes number of bottles*/
    printf ("Taking a shower you use %d bottles of water", numbtl);
    return 0;
}
```